# Is there a way to make an in-line tag?

Tags: cross-referencing, symbols, hyperlink, tag

I know that I can use labels in an in-line equation, but since it is an in-line equation I didn’t want this equation to be numbered, instead I would like to reference it by an \star, and keep the hyperlink property, just like it is possible with `\tag` in the `\begin{equation} .... \end{equation}`, but \tag does not seem to work in the `\begin{math} .... \end{math}` that is an in-line equation environment.

Comment: `hyperref` comes with `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla (this is  \hypertarget{Pythagoras}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$} \dots

\lipsum[1-6]

As evident from \hyperlink{Pytagoras}{Pytagoras' formula} \dots
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot Your second `\hyperlink` is one `h` short, or your first `\hypertarget` is too long by one `h` :)

Comment: Although @marmot has given a recipe for doing this, I wonder how a reader is going to find the reference if the document isn't read online with a live linking capability.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In the old-fashioned way, i.e. calling the relation Pythagoras' theorem and expecting the reader to know it. You can add it to the index, too.